# Translation using PySide outside the constructor

Tags: python, qt, internationalization

I am using pySide and try to internationalize my project. The problem is that none of the Strings get translated if I do not translate them through the constructor.
I would like to translate the Strings in other methods as well. What could be the problem?

Here is my module:

```
    class InterpolationView(QWidget):

     def __init__(self, parent=None, flags=Qt.Widget):
       super(InterpolationView, self).__init__(parent, flags)
       load_ui('ui/wizards/interpolation/interpolation_view.ui', self)
       self.stepGroupBox.setTitle(Dictionary.map_interpolation_view["step_planning"])
```

I translate my Strings from the injected **.ui** file in the **init** method. The translations come from a module called **Dictionary** that includes all the necessary translations:

```
    class Dictionary(object):

       map_interpolation_view = None

     def __init__(self):
       super(Dictionary, self).__init__()
       self.initialize_dictionary()

     def initialize_dictionary(self):
       Dictionary.map_interpolation_view = dict()
       Dictionary.map_interpolation_view["step_planning"] = QApplication.translate("Dictionary", "Step Planning")
```

The **Dictionary** is initialized in the **MyPlugin** module which is a python plugin.This is where I also initialize my translator.

```
    class MyPlugin(Plugin):

def __init__(self, context):
    super(MyPlugin, self).__init__(context)
    translate_to_german = True
    if(translate_to_german):
        translator = load_translation('de')
        application = QCoreApplication.instance()
        application.installTranslator(translator)
    self.__dictionary = Dictionary()
```

I would like to get rid of this special **Dictionary** module and just translate the Strings like this:

```
    class InterpolationView(QWidget):

     def __init__(self, parent=None, flags=Qt.Widget):
       super(InterpolationView, self).__init__(parent, flags)
       load_ui('ui/wizards/interpolation/interpolation_view.ui', self)


     def translate(self):
       self.stepGroupBox.setTitle(QApplication.translate("InterpolationView", "Step Planning"))
```

and be able to call the **translate** method from any other class. This does not work however, the Strings are not translated then. Why?

Comment: Please show some actual code that demonstrates the problems.